# How to publish my .net core code and deploy in AWS Windows Instance with gitlab yml file

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-code-deploy, cicd

My code .net core added in GitLab and my web application deploys in AWS windows instance IIS.
How to write yml file to automatically publish and deploy my code in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If possible please share whatever you have tried so far, I am just sharing high level steps here.

First prepare the .gitlab-ci.yml file then add following lines

```
script:
  - bash .gitlab-deploy-dev.sh
```

Inside .gitlab-deploy-dev.sh you should add

```
ssh ec2-use@server 'git pull origin dev && aws s3://bucket/dev-config.json .............. '
```

Then run the pipeline